# Best mathematical expression between 3 clocks under the given circumstances.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

There are two clocks C1 and C2 are synchronized with a common clock (Cs) having a timing uncertainty of 20ms, means from reference common clock their (individually) accuracy would be within 20ms range (as shown in the figure).
Along with this uncertainty (~20ms) the clock C1 and C2 have the additional uncertainty of 5ms due to the clock frequency mismatch between them. 
**Now, How can I draw any effective mathematical relationship among them?**

[image: Image of the clock relationship.]

N.B. C1 and C2 update simultaneously. C1 and C2 get updates by Cs with an uncertainty of ~20ms. However, due to the clock error C1 (and C2) develops the time such that a ~5m additional uncertainty creates between them (C1 and C2).

Comment: Are C1 & C2 synchronized simultaneously? I.e. assuming C1 & C2 are perfect would they show the same time.

Comment: They update simultaneously. Cs is very constant. But C1 and C2 get updates by Cs with an uncertainty of ~20ms due to propagation delay. However, due to the individual clock error of C1 and C2, C1 (and C2) develop the time such that a ~5m additional uncertainty creates between them (C1 and C2).